# Best practice when running out of progressive file names

Tags: filenames

Since this problem is not tied to any specific language I will keep it as general as possible. I have a function that takes a path `P` (not a directory) and a number `N` as parameters, and behaves like so:

1. If `P` doesn't exist it creates a file at `P`;
2. If `P` exists it adds a progressive numeric string `P_0000` (the number of `0`s depends on the number of digits of `N`) and checks if the new progressive string exists, if it doesn't it goes on until it reaches `N`.

My question is: is there a standard best practice on how to handle the case where all possible progressive names are already taken? Do I simply non create a file? Do I overwrite the first one telling the user? What's the least dangerous approach?

I know this is a general question, and because of this I don't even know how to look for advice (nor how to properly tag the question) if not by asking here. Thanks in advance to all who will answer.

Comment: If you run out of file names, why not augment the already created files? I mean like concatenating many files to a single one path. I am not aware of any best practice for this though. Just a suggestion.

Comment: The purpose of N was to limit the number of files, theoretically it can be thought of as an N large enough that you cannot go over it. This was just to wander if there are any best practices or conventions for when one really runs out of names

Comment: Some places use a combination of the yyyy-mm-dd date and a sequence number.  The date makes it easier to find files amongst the millions.

Comment: There is no standard, because it will depend on your use case what to do. It might be ok to overwrite old files and just restart the counter at `_0000` or it might be necessary to add an additional digit, or it might be necessary to throw an error. Who knows ...